# How to edit values of TextEditingController Object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to Change the Values inside TextEditingController Object. If I press a button last one digit should get deleted. Like a BackSpace Operation. Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.text =
              controller.text.substring(0, controller.text.length - 1);
        },
        tooltip: 'decrement',
        child: Icon(Icons.backspace),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```